# How do I edit contacts on FaceTime, when icons don't show

Tags: facetime

When I try to do video with one of my contacts on facetime on my ipad mini, there is no video or audio icon next to her name.  My other facetime contacts have the icons.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Checking your contact's details might help. It could be that you have certain details (e.g. Work email but not personal email or number) that is not linked to their Apple id and facetime